# Javascript Autocomplete Loading Slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, autocomplete

i'm working on a Javascript based form for all area of India. i want it to be as Autocomplete. but everything is working fine but whem i'm trying search all Javascript Objects(for End-Users) is loading very slow. any developer help can lead me to fix this issue/Bug.

Comment: Autocomplete loading can be slow depending on how you have divided all area of india. How many elements are you searching and is your search storage optimized for such search.

Comment: thank you @FarrukhSubhani . i worked on external linking the javascript within same web server